# How to properly bring a java library from github to replace dependency in maven project

Tags: java, git, maven, github

So I have worked with git my fair share, but only with one project at a time. I have a project (call it projectA) that currently uses maven to bring in a java library (call it libraryB) that is used in projectA as a dependency. I have made some code to do something that libraryB couldn't do before (for example, it has a database connector class and I made a version that supports security). I want to commit the relevant code up to libraryB, but I don't know the best way to go about doing so. Also, projectA just has the maven dependency of libraryB currently, so it is unmodifiable. So I want to replace the unmodifiable libraryB dependency with my github fork of libraryB, put my classes and changes into it, and then do a pull request into master of libraryB on git.

Sorry if that is at all confusing with how I worded it, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper way to get `projectA` using your changes to `libraryB`.

1) Make pull request of your changes to `libraryB`.

2) Get approved and have your changes merged into `libraryB`.

3) Have `libraryB` build and deployed to remote Maven repository with newer jar version.

4) Update your `libraryB` jar dependency in your pom to the newer version and do a new maven build.

All of above assume that `libraryB` gets deployed to the remote Maven repository that is configured in your `settings.xml`. If it is deployed to central Maven repository then you should automatically get the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

Tsolakp's answer is what you want in the long run.
If library B is discontinued or has a long release cycle(meaning you could be a long time waiting for a new release):

After you've made changes to B, `mvn install` (or equivalent) into your local repo.

Then change the version of B referred to in A to the version you installed.

Note that, if you push A's changes this will require everyone working on A to first install B, including CI servers.